# Should I use "the rest is" or "the rest are" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> After eating the sausages, Mary pointed at the cherry tomatoes and
>   smashed potatoes and said, "I bet the rest is/are tasty too."

Should it be are or is this case? To me is sounds more natural but are sounds more logical because there "rest" consists of two items?

Comment: Do you mean "mashed potatoes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either. If "cherry tomatoes and smashed potatoes" is a single dish you could treat it as singular example

> Fish and chips is a traditional British meal
>
> Mashed potatoes goes well with gravy.

If you imagine the tomatoes and potatoes as separate items, then use "are"

> The fish and chips are fried in oil.

I prefer "is", because I think of it as being one meal.